How to search query in Django JSONField Model?
I have been trying to resolve this issue for the past 2 days, but I have not found a solution yet. I have scoured the internet, Django Forum, and ChatGPT, and attempted over 50 methods, but nothing seems to work.
Our Model:
class Order(models.Model):
    Payment_Refrence = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    Order_ID = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, default=unique_order_id)
    OrderData = models.JSONField(max_length=100000, null=True, blank=True)

Order Data Creation
OrderDataCreate = {
    'product_title': Product.title,
    'product_description': Product.description,
    'product_plans': ProductPlans,
    'package': Package_name,
}

Dump Data:
CreateOrder = Order.objects.create(
    OrderData=json.dumps(OrderDataCreate),
)

After Dump Data in Database ~ code from Database
"{\"product_title\": \"Redis API Implementition\", \"product_description\": \"Description Here\",}"

I have implemented this to search:
OrderData = Order.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
if SearchQuery:
    SearchQuery = inpvalidator.anyname_validation(SearchQuery)
    search_filters = Q(OrderData__contains={'product_title': SearchQuery})
    OrderData = OrderData.filter(search_filters)
    print(f'Search Filtered=======>{OrderData.count()}')

I even tried this:
OrderData = OrderData.filter(OrderData__product_title__icontains=SearchQuery)

I'm not getting any results.

I'm not sure what the contents of the variable SearchQuery are, but the following filter should work as per the official documentation:
OrderData__product_title__icontains=SearchQuery

You can double check the contents of the variable SearchQuery

Our SearchQuery includes "Text" for searching Order History, functioning with fields like Order_ID but not with the json field. I have also well defined on Django Community: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-to-search-query-in-django-jsonfield-model/31802/2
